# Is it possible to mix QTextStream and QDataStream?

Tags: c++, qt, file-io

Needing to read a mixed text/binary file I thought using both `QTextStream` and `QDataStream` together would be the most effective.

The file looks like this:

> Some line of text
>  Another line of text
>  42
>  <100 bytes of
>   binary data>
>  12
>  <100 bytes of binary data>
>  ... etc. (an
>   int in a line, then 100 bytes of binary data in a line, and so on)

Here is the initialization, variables etc.:

```
// a QFile named in is already opened successfully as binary (without QIODevice::Text)
QTextStream stream(&in);
QDataStream data(&in);
int nr;
int nr_bytes;
char buffer[200];
```

First I tested whether reading from one stream advances the other. If I read 10 bytes with `data.readRawData()` from the file, then `stream.readLine()` will read "of text", so it works!

However, if I do the following, from the beginning of the example file:

```
stream.readLine();
stream.readLine();
for (/*...*/)
{
    stream >> nr;
    stream.readLine();
    nr_bytes = data.readRawData(buffer, 100);
    stream.readLine();
}
```

it does not work, and the buffer remains empty. Strangely, the numbers (42, 12, etc.) are read correctly into `nr`, no matter how many bytes I read with `data.readRawData()`. It can be 1000 bytes, it still does not seem to read anything. The value in `nr_bytes`, however, indicates that the bytes are successfully read! Still strange, that the last readLine in the loop actually reads the binary data (at least until it encounters a zero, a line feed or other special characters). This means, that `data.readRawData()` did not read anything at all, but it still has the number of required bytes in its return value.

Does this mean I cannot use `QTextStream` and `QDataStream` together, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: I solved it with `std::ifstream`, where you can mix `read()`, `getline()` and `operator>>()` just fine. However, I'm still curious about how can the same be achieved using the `Qt` streams.